# Fair Use of the thumbnail version of thousands of images from a third party?

Tags: images, legal, copyright, thumbnail

I would like to include on my website the thumbnail version of thousands of images created by a third party, which I am trying to contact to ask permission, with no success. I would link from the thumbnail to the original version, hosted in the webservers of this third party, and I would be always citing the original author.

The images are generic landscapes, related to the topic of my website (Africa). I created a thumbnail version, resizing the original dimensions (1024x682) to a square 150x150 pixel cropped thumbnail. These thumbnails, with part of the original image, would be hosted in my webserver.

The third party created millions of images, and I've selected only a part of the original dataset, only those images related to the topic of my website. The purpose is offer information about Africa to the users of my website, linking these original images.

I wondered if this action could be considered as a 'Fair Use' of the contents, in order to avoid legal issues with this third party. I've reading http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/, but I would like to know other point of views.

Comment: I assume you are interested in fair use as defined by the laws and jurisdiction of the United States?

Comment: Yes, Stephen, as defined in the US, since the third party is an US company, and my website is hosted in th US. Thank you!